# Magento 2: How to set multiple session value in an array?

Tags: magento2, session

I know how to set and get session value in magento 2. Here is what I do:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$mysession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$mysession->setMyTestValue('testsession');
$mysession->getMyTestValue();
```

It works fine.

But I want multiple session value in an array; In simple PHP I've achieved this in following way:

```
**//Set session in  an array**
<?php
   foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
   $_SESSION ['mytestvalues'] = array ();
   array_push($_SESSION['mytestvalues'], $_product->getEntityId());
   endforeach;
?>

/**/Get session array**
<?php print_r($_SESSION['mytestvalues']); ?>
```

Same thing I want to achieve in Magento 2. How to achieve this in magento 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected $mysession;

public function __construct(
    -----
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession
    ){
    $this->mysession = $coreSession;
    ----
}
    $this->mysession->setMyTestValue(array());
    $sessionValue = $this->mysession->getMyTestValue();
    $datas = array_push($sessionValue, $_product->getEntityId());
    $this->mysession->setMyTestValue($datas);
```

Comment: Error: Only variables should be passed by reference.

Comment: I have updated my answer.